# When creating a legend in Vega, how do I structure the `entries` key for creating a custom symbol + label?

Tags: vega

I'm creating a legend and would like to customize the symbol + label that is created for each entry using the `encode -> entries` custom mark property.

I can create custom symbols and labels independently via the respective `symbols` and `labels` properties. However, I haven't been able to figure out the format that is expected in the `entries` property; the documentation at https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/legends/ describes the expected value as a pair of symbol + label marks.

I tried the following:

```
{
  "encode": {
    "entries": {
      "update": {
        "marks": [
          {
            "type": "symbol",
            "encode": {
              "enter": {
                "width": {
                  "value": 10
                },
                "fillOpacity": {
                  "value": 1
                },
                "shape": {
                  "value": "square"
                },
                "height": {
                  "value": 10
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "encode": {
              "enter": {
                "text": {
                  "value": "Hi"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```